# Windows cannot find the local profile

Tags: windows-xp, user-profiles

My computer was infected and the damage was almost completely removed. The only problem that persists is that my local profile on **Windows XP** is corrupted. When I try to log on, I get the following message:

> Windows cannot find the local profile and is logging you on with a
>   temporary profile. Changes you make to this profile will be lost when
>   you log off.

My desktop icons still exist at C:\Documents and Settings\USER\desktop but I don't know how to restore them.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the SID of the user gets a .bak in the registry to restore to a working version, but it may not. Either go into another user that works with administrator privilege, or reboot the machine into safe mode (press F8 as the machine boots, choose Start Windows in safe mode).

From there:

1. Go to `Start` -> `Run`
2. Type `regedit`
3. Find the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList`
4. Look on the list on the left for your SID's
   [image: SIDs]
   *Windows 10 but the same process in XP*
5. You will likely have one (or more) SIDs that have a .bak)

*Example:*

*S-1-5-21-2810719073-3206633882-1157864446-1002*

*S-1-5-21-2810719073-3206633882-1157864446-1002.bak*

6. Export the SID WITHOUT .bak somewhere on your machine in case you need it again
7. Delete the key WITHOUT .bak
8. Rename the key WITH .bak, removing the .bak
9. Reboot your machine and try your user account again

Comment: How did you find that registry key and it's function?

Comment: I faced this issue on a Windows 8 PC. For me, the exact steps mentioned in this answer didn't help. So I went a step further using the steps in the answer. I deleted both **SID** and **SID.bak** hives from registry. It solved the problem. When I logged in from the same account next time, it started from scratch as if I was using the PC for the first time ever. Thanks Jonno for helping the community.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a backup of all your data just delete and recreate your profile.
Once backed up, login with another account and go to control panel, open System, Advanced tab, User profiles, Click Settings, select profile, delete.

Only do this if you're data is backed up and willing to recreate your icon layout, personal appearance settings, etc, but if your only worried about icons, documents, favorites just back those up.

Comment: I tried it after logging in with another account but I am not able to delete the problematic profile. The delete button is disabled as shown in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMQKX.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem, which was maddening, I am using Windows XP Professional SP3, fully updated.

I solved this problem by

1. Navigate to Computer Management (right click Computer on Desktop and select Manage)
2. Expand Local Users and Groups,
3. Select Groups,
4. Go to the right pane and select Administrators.

   All members of Administrative Group will be displayed. Below them is an Add button.
5. Select Add.

   A Select Users screen will display, at the bottom of which is an Advanced button.
6. Select Advanced Button.

   An expanded Select Users box will display.
7. Press button which reads Find Now.

   The bottom formerly blank box (former to Find Now) will populate with all available selections. It's up to you to determine which of these selections is giving you trouble.
8. Select the troublesome one from the list and proceed to add it to administrators.

My problems disappeared after doing so. Your mileage may vary. Good luck.

Comment: _Windows XP [...] fully updated_ Thanks, that might me giggle (despite this week's ransomware outbreak)...